# Why the introduction of __slots__ was made possible with descriptors?

Tags: python, slots, python-descriptors

In [this blog post](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html) from the series "The History of Python", Guido van Rossum states:

> Another enhancement made possible with descriptors was the introduction of the __slots__ attribute on classes.

I understand this sentence as: under the hood __slots__ is implemented by descriptors.

But contrary to this my interpretation, Guido van Rossum writes a few lines later:

> Underneath the covers, the implementation of this feature is done entirely in C and is highly efficient.

So, __slots__ is not implemented by descriptors?

But two sentences later, again he writes:

> Not only was __slots__ an interesting application of descriptors, ...

So, what's actually the case with __slots__ and descriptors?

Is __slots__ implemented by descriptors or not? And if yes: how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statements don't contradict themselves. The attributes defined by `__slots__` are descriptors on the created class **and** the implementation of that descriptor is written in C (assuming CPython).

The descriptor class is called `member_descriptor` as can be seen by this example code:

```
import inspect

class Test:
    __slots__ = 'a',
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

type(Test.a)                        # member_descriptor
inspect.isdatadescriptor(Test.a)    # True
inspect.ismemberdescriptor(Test.a)  # True
```

And a quick search on the CPython repository on GitHub revealed [the C implementation of it (Link for CPython version 3.8.0)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Objects/descrobject.c#L736-L771).

---

To go into a bit more detail:

A Python class is essentially a `dict` with (a lot of) bells and whistles. On the other hand there are Python-C-classes that use a C-`struct` to implement a Python class. Such a C-struct is faster and requires (significantly) less memory than a dictionary even if it only contains Python objects (which is basically a C-array containing references to Python objects).

To make it possible that "normal" Python classes could benefit from the faster access and the reduced memory footprint `__slots__` was introduced. A class with `__slots__` will be translated essentially to a C-struct. However to make it possible that the attribute lookup/setting/deletion map to the corresponding `struct` member some sort of translation layer (descriptors) is required. That translation layer for members defined in `__slots__` is `member_descriptor`.

So when you look up the attribute on an instance of a `__slots__`-class you'll get a `member_descriptor` and that `member_descriptor` will know how to get/set/delete the member of the underlying C-`struct`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a simple class:

```
class A:
    __slots__ = ('a',)
```

What is `a`? It's a descriptor:

```
>>> type(A.a)
<class 'member_descriptor'>
```

Each string in the value of `__slots__` is used to create a class attribute by that name with a `member_descriptor` value.

That means you can (try to) access it via `A.a.__get__`

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: a
```

assign to it with `A.a.__set__`

```
>>> a.a = 7
```

and try to access it again :)

```
>>> a.a
7
```

What you *can't* do is try to assign to any other attribute on the instance:

```
>>> A.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'b'
>>> a.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'b'
>>> a.b = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'b'
```

The presence of `__slots__` not only creates the requested class attributes, but *prevents* the creation of any additional attributes on an instance.